# Moving a shape using KeyListener while another shape is moving independently

Tags: java

I am fairly new to Java and programming in general. I am developing a small game where the user plays as a white square whose objective is to collect all of the coins on screen. As the user collects coins moving red squares appear on the screen that will end the game if the user touches them. I use KeyListener to move the user's square.

The problem I am encountering is that I cannot move the player's square while a red square is moving. The red square will move when a while loop is activated within the paint method. I would like the user to be able to move their square while a red square is moving.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class FinalGame extends Canvas
{



    private static final long  serialVersionUID   =1L;
    //refers to players coordinates
    static int x=230, y=230;
    static boolean coin1=true;
    static int coinsCollected=0;
    static int mj;
    static boolean bounce=true;
    public FinalGame() {
        setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        setBackground(Color.black);
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                moveSquare(e);
            }
        });
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
          //refers to coin's coordinates
            int c1x=20; int c1y=20;


            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(x,y,20,20);

            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.fillOval(c1x, c1y, 20, 20);

            if((x==c1x)&&(c1y==20))
                {
                    coin1=false;

                }
            if(coin1==false)
                {
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.fillOval(20, 20, 20, 20);



                int j=230;
                mj=5;

//I am unable to move the square while this loop is active

                while(bounce)
                    {       

                        repaint();
                        if((j==480)||(j==0))
                            {
                                mj=-mj;
                            }

                        j=j+mj;

                        g.setColor(Color.red);
                        g.fillRect(230, j, 20, 20);

                        delay();

                        g.setColor(Color.black);
                        g.fillRect(230, j, 20, 20);

                        g.setColor(Color.white);
                        g.fillRect(x,y,20,20);



                    }
                mj=-mj;


                }

            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(x,y,20,20);

        }

    public void moveSquare(KeyEvent e)
        {
            switch(e.getKeyCode())
            {
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    y += 5;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    y-= 5;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    x-=5;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                    x+=5;
                    break;
            }
            repaint();
        }
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Basic Game");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                FinalGame ex = new FinalGame();
                frame.getContentPane().add(ex);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                ex.requestFocus();


        }
    public void delay()
        {
        try
                {
                Thread.sleep(15);
                } catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is as follows:

```
create coins at random

move the player to collect the coins

create red things also at random
```

all these simultaneously.

Therefore you need different threads to enforce this simultaneity.

One thread for the coins one thread for the red things and one the main thread which already exists in the main class:

```
class FinalGame extends Canvas
{

private static final long  serialVersionUID   =1L;
//refers to players coordinates
static int x=230, y=230;
static boolean coin1=true;
static int coinsCollected=0;
static int mj;
static boolean bounce=true;
Red r;
Coin c;
public FinalGame() {
    setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    setBackground(Color.black);
    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            moveSquare(e);
        }
    });
    r=new Red(this);
    r.start();
    c=new Coin(this);
    c.start();      
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        if(x==r.x && y==r.y) System.exit(0);

        if(c.visible) {
          g.setColor(Color.yellow);
          g.fillOval(c.c1x, c.c1y, 20, 20);
        }

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(x,y,20,20);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(r.x, r.y, 20, 20);

    }

public void moveSquare(KeyEvent e)
    {

        switch(e.getKeyCode())
        {
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                y += 5;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                y-= 5;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                x-=5;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                x+=5;
                break;
        }

        repaint();
    }

public void m()
    {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Basic Game");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            frame.getContentPane().add(this);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            requestFocus();

    }

class Coin extends Thread {
  int c1x=20, c1y=20;
  boolean visible=true;
  FinalGame f;

  public Coin(FinalGame f) {
    this.f=f;
  }

  public void run() {

    while(true)
    {       

        if((f.x==c1x)&&(c1y==20))
        {
                visible=false;

        }               
    }


  }
}


class Red extends Thread {
  int x=130, y=10;
  FinalGame f;

  public Red(FinalGame f) {
    this.f=f;
  }

  public void run() {

            int mj=5;

            while(true)
                {       

                    if((y==480)||(y==0))
                        {
                            mj=-mj;
                        }

                    y=y+mj;

    f.repaint();

    try
    {
            Thread.sleep(15);
    } catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }


  }
}
```

}

Comment: No, you don't need new thread for every moving object, that's silly. One new thread for game loop that moves and renders everything is enough.